# Not able to extract data in forloop using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and Python. I am trying to extract data from website("https://in.bookmyshow.com/bengaluru/movies") using forloop but it dosen't seem to be working

```
def parse(self, response):
      for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="mv-row"]'):
          item = ExampleItem()
          item['Moviename'] = sel.xpath('.//a[@class="__movie-name"]//text()').extract()
          item['Language'] = sel.xpath('.//li[@class="__language"]//text()').extract()
          item['Info'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="__rounded-box __genre"]/text()').extract()
          yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locators themselves are correct, you just need to fix the container locator you are looping over:

Replace:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="mv-row"]'):
```

with:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "movie-card")]'):
```